# How to change an rgb value in a javascript string of css styles to hex value with regex + replace

Tags: regex, replace

I have been struggling with this for a while now so I thought I would ask here to see if anyone can help me out.

I have a string of css styles in javascript which looks like this:

```
width: 250px; background-color: rgb(48, 44, 48);
```

I am trying to replace the rgb value in the string with a hex value by running it through a function I have called RGBtoHEX so I am left with a string like the following:

```
width: 250px; background-color: #302C30;
```

I am struggling to create the regex to get the rgb string from the main string to pass to the function.

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
str.replace(
    /\brgb\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/g,
    function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
        return "#" + ("0"+Number($1).toString(16)).substr(-2) + ("0"+Number($2).toString(16)).substr(-2) + ("0"+Number($3).toString(16)).substr(-2);
    })
```

Comment: This works but I have no idea why. Is there anywhere I can read up on how the function inside replace() works? Thanks

Comment: @Rob Taylor: The function passed to `replace` is called for each match and the matches of each sub-pattern is passed to it (first argument is the whole matched string). See [Mozilla’s reference for `String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for further information. And `Number(x).toString(16)` is just used to turn the string into hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the css line in a string and extracting the rgb values character by character.

Comment: I already have the css line in a string. How would I extract the rgb values from the string?

Comment: Try using the substring() function. Also, for further reference, read http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp