# Replace rgb values in multiple divs with hex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out a way to replace all rgb values inside of a string (which contains HTML code) with the hex equivalent.

I've found a small function which converts rgb2hex, but i can't seem to figure out a way to replace multiple rgb values inside of a string. Can someone please guide me in the right direction as to what I need to do?

Here's an example of the string, i'm trying to replace each rgb value with its relevant hex code

```
//example need help 
var test = '
<div style="background-color:rgb(21,233,21)"></div>
<div style="background-color:rgb(43,123,43)"></div>
'
```

I've also created a basic fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Ldq3ckh0/

Any help or guidance in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529752/how-to-change-an-rgb-value-in-a-javascript-string-of-css-styles-to-hex-value-wit

Comment: But why? All modern browsers support RGB.

Comment: This is for an email builder tool, some email clients do not support RGB

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
test.replace(/rgb\([^\)]+\)/g, function(rgb) {
    return rgb2hex(rgb);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldq3ckh0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I've managed to get this working by using the following code

```
                var test = "width: 250px; background-color: rgb(48, 44, 48); background-color: rgb(23, 212, 23);"

                var output = test.replace(
                    /\brgb\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/g,
                    function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
                        return "#" + ("0"+Number($1).toString(16)).substr(-2) + ("0"+Number($2).toString(16)).substr(-2) + ("0"+Number($3).toString(16)).substr(-2);
                    })
```